# Outlook add-in check inline reply mode

Tags: outlook-web-addins, office-store, officedev

I was forwarded to stackoverflow for questions.

I have created an addin for outlook that i want to publish on Add-ins store.
I have received failures on my application that i need to resolve.

When the user has made the action in my add-in. I close the email with
"Office.context.mailbox.item.close()"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messagecompose?view=outlook-js-1.5#close--

When using Outlook Desktop and replying with "inline reply mode" this method does not work. Is there a way to check if the mail is in "inline reply mode" or not?

I have made a image to be shown that the process is finished and i hope this works since closing the taskpane does not work.

Comment: Your last paragraph mentions that **closing the taskpane does not work**. Was that just a typo since your post is about closing the email instead of the taskpane?

Comment: Hi,
 
We got the failure on the application to the add-in store because of the "task pane is still open". but the problem was that the email was not closed.

 But i have created an image to be shown and calling close() so if the inline reply mode is not working the user gets an image instead presenting him that the email is sent and he needs to close.

Comment: Have you tried closing the taskpane using the closeContainer API? Here's a link to the documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=word-js-preview#closecontainer--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted above, `Office.context.mailbox.item.close()` does not work for inline replies in the desktop Outlook client. Unfortunately, we have no way of checking whether the email is in **inline reply mode** or not. We have a [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page where we track feature requests. Please don't to add a feature request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.